# Removing SQLite column of table of which there are foreign constraints

Tags: sqlite

I needed to delete a column from a table that other tables had a foreign constraint on.  I guess `ALTER TABLE` doesn't let you remove columns, so I had to create a new table without the column and copy the data over and rename them appropriately. Though now it won't let me delete the old table with the extra column because of foreign table constraints still I guess pointing to the old table instead of the new one... even though the new one now has the correct name. What is the recommended practice for making the foreign keys point to the right table now that I did the switch?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can. You might have to recreate all the other tables with the updated foreign key, because you cannot change foreign key constraint conditions or at least as far as I know.